# record events & generate puppeteer script automatically, is it doable without chrome extension puppeteer-recorder?

Tags: puppeteer

Is below thing possible with puppeteer ?
e.g

```
i open http://localhost:3000 where one Html Form with URL is there.
if  i enter url = "amazon.com" and press go then recording will automatic start ( event recording ) 
in new tab i just search product and add to cart it 
then stop recording by visiting http://localhost:3000 page button 
so one recording is saved with events 
Now in this page all recording will be shown 
And when i play "amazon.com" recording then it will run step number 2 to 3 automatically add product into cart
```

Pl. help me just want to know is it possible ?
I am able to run with static script but i need to create dynamic script each timeThanks in Advance
is it doable without chrome extension  ?
Please help someone
is it doable ?

Comment: What is the problem using puppeteer-recorder?